# Generate Random Encryption Key with time tick and store it on client and DB Server Windows Application Form C#

Tags: c#, database, encryption

Google Authenticator, Authy, and similar authentication applications used for providing Second Factor Authentication have a clock in them.

I want t use the same approach i.e.

1. Generate a random encryption key for each user (non-admin)
2. Link each key generated to the user based on his ID i.e (user1 ID = 1 RandomEncryptionKey = G3er@jkd83jasd linked using some sort of a function)
3. Store the encryption key on both server and client and the keys would change based on the DateTime function+ 5 seconds tick

How I can do that?

I found this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.generateiv?view=net-5.0) but it did help me a place to start!

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware that these applications are more than "similar" and are using a standard called TOTP? Is there a reason you think you need to build this yourself?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever nope i am not aware of that and I do not know anything about TOTP I donno if it has what I need... Can you refer a link to work with?

Answer (score 1):

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out in the comments you should have a look into the standard **TOTP** and the underlying algorithm **HOTP** that was defined by the Internet Engineering Task Force.

You can find the full definition of the **HOTP** algorithm here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4226

Also here is a guide that looks very helpful for your question:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-time-based-one-time-passwords-work-and-why-you-should-use-them-in-your-app-fdd2b9ed43c3/

Comment: Thanks for the links mate but this not what I was looking for. You see, TOTP addresses passwords and codes I want something to handle the encryption keys themselves to be time-based. Ever heard of 3D3X security? It's one of the projects I am working on